# how to create a cookie in javascript and use in controller in mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcextensions

Actually I am having a requirement like :

I need to get the ID's of checked records by using Javascript and store the id's in a cookie and access that cookie in controller and delete the records based on that id's

My Javascript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    function SelectionChanged(s, e)
    {

        s.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
    }
    function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values)
    {
        SelectedRows.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            SelectedRows.ClearItems();
            var s = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                //SelectedRows.AddItem(values[i]);
                s=s+values[i]+',';

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            document.cookie = s;
        }
        $("#count").html(gvRowSelection.GetSelectedRowCount());

    }
    // ]]>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is specifically, but if you're looking for a way to set cookies via Javascript, check out the [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). You'd access it in your controller just like you would any other cookie:

**Javascript**

```
$.cookie('mycookie', 'myvalue');
```

**C#**

```
Request.Cookies["mycookie"].Value;
```

Comment: Do i need to add the plugin in my page ?

Comment: Yes, download the jquery.cookie.js file from the GitHub repository I linked to, add it to your MVC project and then include it with <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script> or wherever you placed the script file.

Comment: I am not able to access that cookie in controller.Its getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

I think Scott was rigth except that you need to Base64 decode the data then JSON decode the data.

**JavaScript**

```
$.jCookies({name:'user',value:{name:'brian',level:'awesome'}});
```

**C#**

```
Convert.FromBase64String(Page.Request.Cookies["user"].Value)
```

For more information look at the following Page: [Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/04/j-is-for-jcookies-http-cookie-handling-for-jquery/)